# In R, taking differences between values in two rows based on values in other rows, with specific requirements

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a bunch of rows (1000s) of data with multiple subjects that I have a pretty basic question for, but am very unsure how to go about answering it. Below is an example of what my data frame looks like.

```
     Subject  Time Current.State Transition.State Transition.Event L2 L1 C R2 R1 FoodCup
14       KM6   435            16               15                0  0  0 0  0  0       0
15       KM6   455            15                4                0  0  0 0  0  0       0
16       KM6   648             4                7                3  0  0 1  0  0       0
17       KM6   658             7               14                0  0  0 0  0  0       0
18       KM6   691            14               16                8  0  0 0  0  0       1
19       KM6   698            16                0                0  0  0 0  0  0       0
20       KM6   721            16               15                0  0  0 0  0  0       0
21       KM6   741            15                4                0  0  0 0  0  0       0
22       KM6   758             4                0                0  0  0 0  0  0       1
23       KM6   762             4                0                0  0  0 0  0  0       0
24       KM6   810             4                7                6  0  0 0  0  1       0
25       KM6   814             7                0                0  0  0 0  0  0       0
26       KM6   815             7                0                0  0  0 1  0  0       0
27       KM6   819             7                0                0  0  0 1  0  0       0
28       KM6   820             7               14                0  0  0 0  0  0       0
29       KM6   821            14                0                0  0  0 0  0  0       0
30       KM6   822            14                0                0  0  0 1  0  0       0
31       KM6   824            14                0                0  0  0 0  0  0       0
32       KM6   829            14                0                0  0  0 1  0  0       0
33       KM6   862            14               16                8  0  0 0  0  0       1
34       KM6   863            16                0                0  0  0 0  0  0       1
```

The task I'm looking to complete is:

How much `Time` passes between a `Transition.State == 7` and a `FoodCup == 1`, but only for the first `FoodCup == 1` since the last `Transition.State == 7`.

For example, I want to be able to take the time in row 16 (648) because that row has a `Transition.State == 7`, then take the time (691) from row 18 because it is the first `FoodCup == 1` after row 16, and then get a value of that time difference (691-648). But I want to completely ignore row 22, even though it has a `FoodCup == 1`, since there was no `Transition.State == 7` "directly" above it.

The desired output would be a new `data.frame` with every occurrence of this with its time difference per `Subject` (not shown here, but there are multiple in the actual `df`s)

I hope this makes sense.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following will do what you want.

```
fun <- function(DF, want = 7){
  st <- which(DF[['Transition.State']] == want)
  fc <- which(DF[['FoodCup']] == 1)
  i <- findInterval(fc, st)
  i <- i[is.finite(i)][1]
  DF[['Time']][fc[i]] - DF[['Time']][st[i]]
}

fun(df1)
#[1] 43

fun(df1, 14)
#[1] 33
```

**Data in `dput` format.**

```
df1 <-
structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
.Label = "KM6", class = "factor"), Time = c(435L, 455L, 648L, 
658L, 691L, 698L, 721L, 741L, 
    758L, 762L, 810L, 814L, 815L, 819L, 820L, 821L, 822L, 824L, 
    829L, 862L, 863L), Current.State = c(16L, 15L, 4L, 7L, 14L, 
    16L, 16L, 15L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
    14L, 14L, 16L), Transition.State = c(15L, 4L, 7L, 14L, 16L, 
    0L, 15L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 14L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    16L, 0L), Transition.Event = c(0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 8L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 8L, 0L), 
    L2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), L1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), C = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L), R2 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), R1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), FoodCup = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("14", 
"15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", 
"26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34"))
```